# Pandas, how to create a fully filled DF while using groupby()

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to fill a dataframe with a calculated demand value extracted from a bigger df. The idea is to understand the behavior of a specific variable (demand in time)

if i use `df1.groupby(['product_title', 'supplier_name', 'date'])['difference'].sum().fillna(0)`
I get the following result:

```
product_title       supplier_name date  
Adults-Blue (mask)  WEI           06/03/20  5
                                  06/05/20  1
                    iYV           06/04/20  3
                                  06/05/20  4
                                  06/07/20  2
```

**But the result I need is the following result (1):**

```
product_title       supplier_name date      demand
Adults-Blue (mask)  WEI           06/03/20  5
Adults-Blue (mask)  WEI           06/05/20  1
Adults-Blue (mask)  iYV           06/04/20  3
Adults-Blue (mask)  iYV           06/05/20  4
Adults-Blue (mask)  iYV           06/07/20  2
```

I also tried creating a new column in the original dataframe by using:

```
df1['demand'] = df1.groupby(['product_title', 'supplier_name', 'date'])['difference'].sum().fillna(0)
```

But I get an index error:

```
TypeError: incompatible index of inserted column with frame index
```

Understandably because I am generating a smaller dataframe. What can I do to get result (1)?

Comment: Can you add an example of the original dataframe?

Comment: After all your operations do ```.reset_index()``` because group by uses the key of the group by as index in the grouped result. Reset index will put them again as separate values in columns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made up some toy data to give you some working code. As noted, you could use `reset_index` but that requires more code than this solution. Here is how you do it.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'Animal': ['Falcon', 'Falcon',
                              'Parrot', 'Parrot'],
                   'Max Speed': [380., 370., 24., 26.]})

df['mean_speed_animal'] = df.groupby(['Animal']).transform('sum').fillna(0)
print(df)
```

Comment: I solved the issue thanks to your advise:  df1['demand'] = df1.groupby(['product_title', 'supplier_name', 'date'])['difference'].transform('sum').fillna(0)

Comment: glad I could help!